# Inclusion and projection are continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $m \geq n$. Prove that the inclusion $\eta:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, x \rightarrow (x,0)$ and the projection $\pi:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, (x,y) \rightarrow x$ are continuous functions.

The inclusion part is easier, as you can take $\varepsilon \geq 0, \delta = \varepsilon, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and argue that:

$d(x,y) < \delta$, for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ implies that $d(\eta(x), \eta(y)) = d(x, y) < \delta = \varepsilon$

However, to prove the projection part, the logic is a bit trickier. Tried to prove that it is a Lipschitz function but I was unsuccessful.

Can anybody help on that?

Comment: It is Lipschitz continuous...can you show your work?

Comment: Do you have to do it with the metric definition? The fact that $\pi$ is continuous follows by taking $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open and noting that $\pi^{-1}(U) = U \times \mathbb{R}^{m-n}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @ArcticChar There is not much to show, as I couldn't specify the Lipschitz constant...

Comment: @User203940 not necessarily through the metric definition. But I'm not sure I understood your proposal!

Comment: I guess what I was writing assumes that you know the product of two open sets is open. Is this fine?

Comment: Both maps are linear maps. Linear maps from a finite dimensional normed space into another normed space are continuous. It suffices to see what happen at the origin.

Comment: @User203940 Yes, it's fine!

Comment: So we want to look at the preimage of a set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ under $\pi$. This is the set of all elements $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ so that $\pi(x) \in U$. We know what the projection looks like on the first $n$ coordinates (so if $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m)$, we know $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in U$). What can the last $m-n$ coordinates look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presupposing we know that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m-n}$ is open, then $U \times V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is open, then we just take $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and we note that $\pi^{-1}(U) = U \times \mathbb{R}^{m-n}$ is open for all $U$ open. Thus $\pi$ is continuous.

Let's do the less cheeky answer now. Recall that distance in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is induced by the norm, so $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$. Writing it out in coordinates, if $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m)$ and $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ we have

$$ d_m(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m (x_i - y_i)^2}.$$

Notice the square root is monotone and $z^2 \geq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$, so we have that

$$ \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m (x_i - y_i)^2}$$

for $n \leq m$. But notice that one the left we have that this is $d_n(\pi(x),\pi(y))$ and on the right this is $d_m(x,y)$. So we have

$$ d_n(\pi(x), \pi(y)) \leq d_m(x,y).$$

So this is actually Lipschitz continuous.